# Is cap_dac_override a superset of cap_dac_read_search?

Tags: permissions, linux-kernel, linux-capabilities

I'm working on limiting capabilities of an existing, complex application and I have been searching for a while for a credible source proving that
permissions included in `cap_dac_override` are a superset of `cap_dac_read_search`.

It seems logical that it is indeed the case, as per [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

> CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE
>       * Bypass file read, write, and execute permission checks.
>
> CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH
>       * Bypass file read permission checks and directory read and execute permission checks;
>       * invoke open_by_handle_at(2);
>       * use the linkat(2) AT_EMPTY_PATH flag to create a link to a file referred to by a file descriptor.

Also, my experiments with capability checks tracer confirm that `cap_dac_override` should suffice. `cap_dac_read_search` appears to be checked before `cap_dac_override` every single time a read access is performed.

I've also found following post on [grsecurity forums](https://forums.grsecurity.net/viewtopic.php?p=16876#p16876), which unfortunetly concerns only `/proc`:

> The way the upstream kernel works is by first checking for CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE and then for CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH for this case.

I'm still uncertain whether is it completely safe to omit `cap_dac_read_search` if I want to grant my application with a  complete read access to the whole filesystem. I'm fully aware that `cap_dac_override` additionally grants write permissions, and I want that.

Would it be possible that somwhere in the kernel there is a place where only a check for `cap_dac_read_search` is made and not for `cap_dac_override`?

Should I include both these capabilities just to be on the safe side or is `cap_dac_read_search` completely redundant in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not. `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` only allows to ignore the permission bits of files. `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` allows to ignore the *read* permission bits and does also allow to execute the system call `open_by_handle_at` which can be used to read outside a container chroot.

See https://github.com/gabrtv/shocker for practical application.

If your application only needs full access to the filesystem then `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` as you have already concluded.

Comment: You're obviously right, funny how manpages explicitly mention it and I've failed to notice this detail. In my case indeed it was just the filesystem access, so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of additional verification and practical tests it seems that it is indeed the case that `cap_dac_override` is a superset of `cap_dac_read_search`.

When `cap_dac_read_search` was removed from the application in question, not a single operation failed because of permissions being denied.